Limitation on Azure App Services startup script
I deployed my web application utilizing Azure App Services. I have startup script which runs the application via command "java -jar test jar -D parameter list". Everything works good,but when I am trying to add a new addintnal parameter to java command using Azure portal, then I got the error popup with the message "failed to save .."
Is it any limitation on startup script content?
Thanks in advance!
I tried to replace one of the existing parameters with a new one and no issues. I could save the changes. Seems startup script has some limitations.

Can you please add the parameter and the code then it would be more understanding.


tried to replace one of the existing parameters with a new one and no issues. I could save the changes. Seems startup script has some limitations.

Azure App Services does have certain constraints and best practices for startup scripts and application settings, but there isn't a strict character limit or parameter limit that would typically cause the error you're seeing.

There's no officially documented limit on the length of the startup command.

There has a limit of 4 KB per application setting. If you are adding a new parameter to an application setting and it exceeds this limit, you might encounter an error.


//Basic Command:
java -jar test.jar

//Adding One Parameter:
java -jar test.jar -Dparameter=value

//Gradually Adding More:
java -jar test.jar -Dparameter1=value1 -Dparameter2=value2

Deployment status (before adding parameters):

Added Additional parameter:

If you use CLI check below:
az webapp config set --resource-group <your-resource-group> --name <your-app-name> --startup-file "java -jar test.jar -Dparameter1=value1 -Dparameter2=value2" 

NOTE:excessively long commands could potentially cause issues. If the command is very long, try shortening it or simplifying it.


Thanks, I moved the command into startup script. I am not sure the command reached to 4kb limit, but in fact after moving to startup script it works
